# Split and sort this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, numbers

I need help writing a script that will take the following array `['James',1,'sam', 16,84,'mason',197]` and put all the numbers into a numbers `array` and all the names into a names `array`. Each array will be in order.

> Output: numbers[1,16,84,197] names ['james','sam','mason']

Comment: This looks like a school exercise. Solve it yourself else you will never learn anything

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt specify a programming language, I recommend python, because it is the easiest one to do this in. Also i suppose that 16,84 is acctualy a floating point of 16.84. Also this only works if the array is formated as [..., name, number, ...]

```
a = ['james', 1, 'sam', 16.84, 'mason', 197]
names = []
numbers = []
for i in range(len(a)//2):
    names += [a[i*2]]
    numbers += [a[i*2+1]]
```

where `a[i*2]` is the current name, and `a[i*2+1]` is the current number.

Comment: I don't think programming languages use commas as decimal seperators as European countries do. `16,84` is two integers seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python I would do the following:

```
array = ['james',1,'sam', 16, 84,'mason',197]
names = [s for s in array if isinstance(s, basestring)]
numbers = [i for i in array if isinstance(i, int)]
```

I am guessing that all the numbers in the list are integers. In case you have any kind of numbers (int, long, float, ...) you can do the following:

```
numbers = [i for i in array if isinstance(i, (int, long, float, complex))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = [], numbers = [];
var array = ['james',1,'sam', 16, 84,'mason',197];

array.forEach(function(item){
 isNaN(item) ? name.push(item) : numbers.push(item);
});
```